# Making a different app by country in Play Store

Tags: android, locale, google-play

I would like my app to appear under different names and appareance in the Play Store depending on the country.

Let's talk about Belgium and France for instance where we both speak french.

In my apk, that's really easy to localize the app with

```
French, Belgium (fr_BE)  
French, France (fr_FR) 
//Same would apply for US- New Zealand, US, UK, etc...
```

So I provided a different look and feel according to their respective flags and specificity, but the problem comes when it is time to publish.

the app is localized as "MyCrazyApp.fr" in France and "MyAwesomeApp.be" in belgium.

Is there a way to make the Play Store display different screenshot and description to these 2 countries?

Comment: No.  It would involve re-publishing the app for each country and filtering it.

Comment: That means 2 different package name, 2 differents apps,... But I guess you are right and there are no magical solution.

Comment: That's not particularly difficult.  What you generally would do is create a shared library containing the core framework and have different projects for each region. Each project would use the shared library. It might be best to do that anyway since the UI is so different for each, but each use the same core functionality. Your package could be "your.package.name.belgium" for the Belgium project and the other could be "your.package.name.france" for the French project.  Since you have the localization figured out, it doesn't sound like you have to do much.

Comment: Yep, indeed.... Thanks! But the customer asked because he wanted to get a huge number of downloads and ratings by comining different coutries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the new developer console that's possible. In the top right there should be an orange link saying "Try the new design".

Normally your developer console would be here:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=...

The new version is here:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/?dev_acc=...

Comment: That's possible by language but not by country. I can filter by french, but belgian and french will get the same name and screenshots.